# How to insert to multiple table from a linked server view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, insert, linked-server

I am new to sql and  hope anyone can help me with this question.

we have a local database called *HR-Master* and a linked server called *SPU* .
There is three tables in our local database namely *EMP*, *REMEMP* and *EMPIC* and one view created from the linked server called *EmployeepassView*

**EMP**

```
ID,LASTNAME,FIRST NAME, MIDNAME,COMID,LASTCHANGED, PERMISSIONS, ALLOWEDPERMISSIONS,ASSET_GROUPID,TR_DBID,QUED,SEGMENTID -
```

**REMEMP**

```
ID ,*JOBROLE,*NATIONALITY ,*PERMITAREAS,DEPT , *ISSUEDATE,*REFID,*TEAMINCHARGE 
 *MAINROLE,*SUBROLE,*ROLENAME,*ROLEID, EXPIRYDATE
```

**EMPPIC**

```
EMPID,OBJECT,TYPE ,*EMP_BLOB,*LASTCHANGED,ACCEPTANCETHRESHOLD, BIO_BODYPAR -
```

**Source**

***EmployeepassView***

```
([COMID],[lastName],[Name_En],[PERTYPE],[REFID],[JobTitle],[Nationality],[PERMITAreas],[IssueDate],[ExpiryDate],[TeamInCharge],[MainRole] ,[SubRolE],[RoleName],[ROLEID],[Picture],[isDisable] ,[LastPersonPrint],[LastPrintDate],[NoOfTimesPrinted],[LastUpdated],
```

I want to copy the values  from my views and put it in the above three tables like this

```
     INSERT dbo.emp ([LASTNAME],[COMID)],[LASTCHANGED])
        INSERT dbo.rememp ([jobrole],[nationality)],[PERMITAREAS], [ISSUEDATE],[REFID],[TEAMINCHARGE], [MAINROLE],[SUBROLE],[ROLENAME],[ROLEID])
        INSERT dbo.emppic ([LASTNAME],[SSNO)],[LASTCHANGED])
    select ([LASTNAME],[COMID)],[LASTCHANGED],[jobrole],[nationality],[PERMITAREAS], [ISSUEDATE],[REFID],[TEAMINCHARGE], [MAINROLE],[SUBROLE],[ROLENAME],[ROLEID],[LASTNAME],[SSNO)],[LASTCHANGED])
from EmployeepassView as ET
where ET.COMID='1234'
```

Using this above query. How can I do this in a single query?Please help

Comment: You can't.  SQL Server only allows you to insert into one table in an `insert` statement.

Comment: You cannot insert into multiple tables using 1 query. It have to be 3 separate insert statements

Comment: So ,  i need to run three insert statement for each table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to do three separate inserts:

If I understand your comment about inserting ID's I am going to assume the EMPID comes from the dbo.emp table.  So I would do the following:

**EDITED FOR STORED PROC:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertStuff @ID int
AS

INSERT dbo.emp ([ID],[LASTNAME],[COMID)],[LASTCHANGED])
 select @ID,[LASTNAME],[COMID)],[LASTCHANGED] from EmployeepassView as ET
 where ET.COMID='1234'

        INSERT dbo.rememp 
SELECT (@ID,[jobrole],[nationality)],[PERMITAREAS], [ISSUEDATE],[REFID],[TEAMINCHARGE], [MAINROLE],[SUBROLE],[ROLENAME],[ROLEID])
select [jobrole],[nationality],[PERMITAREAS], [ISSUEDATE],[REFID],[TEAMINCHARGE], [MAINROLE],[SUBROLE],[ROLENAME],[ROLEID],[LASTNAME],[SSNO)],[LASTCHANGED]) from EmployeepassView as ET
where ET.COMID='1234'

INSERT dbo.emppic ([EMPID],[LASTNAME],[SSNO)],[LASTCHANGED])
select @ID, [LASTNAME],[COMID)],[LASTCHANGED] from EmployeepassView as ET
where ET.COMID='1234'
```

Comment: there is an ID  column common and local  to all three tables How can i insert ID here.

Comment: Where is the ID generated from, i.e. is it an identity column or does it come from somewhere else?  Is it shared across all three tables?

Comment: those three empid is showing as : (PK,int,not null )

Comment: How to pass ID value for the above

Comment: on set @ID=" input value", the first insert is successful but the second insert is not updating the second table and giving an ID null error

Comment: Well your code is not clear at all so I was assuming the first table had an identity field for the ID.  If not then SCOPE_IDENTITY will return a null.  Set ID = "input value"  or whatever value you will be using for ID and then use ID in the insert statement like I showed you above.

Comment: Rather than repeating  ID and COMID, is it possible to create a  store procedure and receive input for both ID and COMID .

Comment: Edited the answer